# Filling in values from one table to another table based on condition

Tags: sql

I have the following table lets call it table A

| DIMENSION | C_TYPE | PERCENTAGE_C_TYPE_DIMENSION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | SA | 64.383541444444 |
| D1 | SB | 29.890972222222 |
| D1 | SC | 5.725486444444 |
| D1 | SD | 0 |
| D2 | SA | 95.243312 |
| D2 | SB | 4.531051 |
| D2 | SC | 0.225637 |

I have another table lets call it Table B

| MONTH_YEAR | DIMENSION | C_TYPE | PERCENTAGE_C_TYPE_DIMENSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021_4 | D1 |  |  |
| 2021_4 | D2 |  |  |

But table B has C_TYPE and PERCENTAGE_C_TYPE_DIMENSION missing or NULLL which we will use from Table A for filling it based on the dimension.
So the new table will look like this

| MONTH_YEAR | DIMENSION | C_TYPE | PERCENTAGE_C_TYPE_DIMENSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021_4 | D1 | SA | 64.38354144 |
| 2021_4 | D1 | SB | 29.89097222 |
| 2021_4 | D1 | SC | 5.725486444 |
| 2021_4 | D1 | SD | 0 |
| 2021_4 | D2 | SA | 95.243312 |
| 2021_4 | D2 | SB | 4.531051 |
| 2021_4 | D2 | SC | 0.225637 |

Lets call it Table C

Notice for dimension D1 and D2 I inserted 4 values of D1 from Table A, and 3 values of D2 from Table A

How do I achieve this in SQL, NOTE I am using Snowflake, and I want to achieve this using a simple query that does not go beyond a join. No procedures, etc.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in an inner join

```
SELECT
    b.month_year,
    b.dimension,
    a.c_type,
    a.PERCENTAGE_C_TYPE_DIMENSION
FROM
    tableA a
JOIN
    tableB b
ON
    a.dimension = b.dimension
```

[SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3db038/1)
[image]